# Ищу компонент для Android

Tags: android, android-customview

Ищу готовый компонент для Android аналогичный по функционалу:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-NxLRjcQsY0

Либо опишите свое видение, как его создавать:
1. На базе чего лучше делать - базовый компонент (View)?
2. Что следует учесть при реализации?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопросы должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: это не один компонент, а целое приложение с множеством разных виджетов и приемов  и расписывать тут, что и как в нем могло бы быть дело муторное.

Comment: Вопрос не в том, чтобы реализовать все приложение, а компонент карточек. Я теряюсь в догадках с чего начать. Вот, например, как мне кажется неплохая "точка опоры": https://habrahabr.ru/company/eastbanctech/blog/267497/  Однако, я думаю, это двлеко не все.

Comment: помню, на хабре была статья как раз про карточки. разрабы какого-то банка выкладывали свой ресайклер, где кредитки накладывались друг на друга при скролле вверх